# An online mp3 AVPlayerItem that failed to play will never play again

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am having trouble playing online mp3 files as AVPlayerItems which have *previously failed to play* due to data connection issues.

**For example:**

1. I try play online mp3 file "FILE_A" with poor data connection and the associated AVPlayerItem fails to play. The AVPlayerItem will then not load and my AVPlayer will stay paused (which is fine for now).
2. Let's say that after a period of time I gain better data connection and play a different online mp3 file "FILE_B" as an AVPlayerItem. The AVPlayer plays this AVPlayerItem with no issues.
3. I then try play the failed file "FILE_A" on good data connection. The AVPlayerItem for "FILE_A" will *always* refuse to play. I can even close/kill the app and try again and "FILE_A" will not play. The only work around is to do a fresh re-install of the app.

**I have 3 questions:**

1. Why does a failed AVPlayerItem never become playable, is there a AVPlayerItem cache in the AVPlayer that always tries to play the failed item?
2. Is there a way to refresh an unplayable AVPlayerItem to make it play again?
3. What is the best way to deinitialize an AVPLayer? Currently I am using `self.player = nil` to deinitialize the player in the deint of my view controller or when a user logs out of their account in the app.

This is how I set up the AVPlayer:

```
self.player = AVPlayer()
self.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .pause
self.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .new, context: nil)
```

This is how I set up an AVPlayerItem and set it as the AVPlayer's currentItem:

```
let url = URL(string: onlineAudioFileUrl)
currentPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: currentPlayerItem)
```

The onlineAudioFileUrl above is String url representing the url of an online mp3 file stored on a server. It has the form:

```
https://ourserver.com/audio_file_name.mp3?Expires=NUMERIC_EXPIRE_TIME&Key-Pair-Id=KEY_PAIR_ID_STRING&Signature=VERY_LONG_SIGNATURE_STRING
```

Comment: Make sure that your player is not nil. You are using optional chaining therefore if it is nil it will fail silently. IMO your issue is setting your player to nil `self.player = nil`. You should add all code that is related to your issue to your post.

Comment: @LeoDabus I do `self.player = nil` in the deinit of the view controller, I have updated my question.

However, your comment does not explain why the failed audio file will not play directly after successfully playing a different file (i.e. when the player is definitely not nil).

Comment: Do you have only one ViewController in your App?

Comment: @LeoDabus No, there are multiple view controllers that use a shared instance of a custom AVPlayer.

Comment: If it is a shared instance why would you set it to nil?  Where is onlineAudioFileUrl and what is its value?

Comment: It is set to nil when the user logs out of their account, since they cannot access the audio player when logged out.

Comment: Are you streaming the audio or downloading it? Are you saving the url string (I mean the file url after downloading)?

Comment: No not streaming, the full audio file is downloaded before it is played. Yes the mp3 file url string is being saved after downloading the audio. I updated my question to show the mp3 url format.

Comment: You are not showing the local file url string and/or the code related to how you are downloading and storing it for later usage. Note that the app is sandboxed so the local file location will be different when you relaunch your app

Comment: Apologies, I think I misunderstood you, the audio is not downloaded and stored locally to the device. I meant that the audio file is not live streamed. An AVPlayerItem is created with the URL and the AVPlayerItem is passed to the player for playing. The AVPlayerItem then loads the entire audio file before playback begins. There is no buffering - playback of the entire AVPlayerItem can either begin or it fails to load and I cannot get it to play again, as is my original question.